# Unable to type within username field within ProtonMail signup page using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

Hi I was trying to type the username field using Selenium and Python for the website https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en.

From the developer tool, I am able to inspect the item using CSSSelector/Xpath or other way. But when I am running the pthon script its not working. Screenshot attached:

[image]

My code is like the following:

```
BASE_URL = 'https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get(BASE_URL)
river.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys('someStringValue')
```

And after executing the following code, geetting the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well from within the browser console: from inspector, right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Email Address* field is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
       driver.get('https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en')
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.usernameWrap iframe[title='Registration form']")))
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input#username"))).send_keys("FunnyBoss")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
       driver.get("https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en")
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='usernameWrap']//iframe[@title='Registration form']")))
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input' and @id='username']"))).send_keys("FunnyBoss")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
       from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
       from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
       from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: protonmail_username_text]

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 0):

Your `xpath` is OK, but the `forms` are inside an `iframe`.

So you need to switch to the iframe first:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(n);
```

Edit: If you read the TOS, you will see

> This Service is provided exclusively to persons. Accounts registered by “bots” or automated methods are not authorized and will be terminated.