# How to send text to the recovery mail field of https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

So im trying to get my first ProtonMail Account Generator working. My Problem is that selenium wont find either the field for the recovery mail or the Create Account button. I switched to the iframe already. Im pretty new and thought that this problem might be caused by the "new" html document which contains the bottom part (starting with the recovery email). Hope someone can help me. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIq5t.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Registration form']"))
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('hallo')

time.sleep(1)

driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_id('passwordc').send_keys('password')

time.sleep(1)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Registration form']"))
driver.find_element_by_id('notificationEmail').send_keys('test')
driver.find_element_by_name('submitBtn').click()
```

Comment: You actually have two iframes you need to switch to instead of just one they both have //iframe[@title='Registration form'] but they differ by one index or class = top or bottom.

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(0);  and driver.switchTo().frame(1); I think should be enough to switch to the frames.

Comment: Yea but what actually helped me was the comment by arundeep chohan but I can't accept it or handle it like an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Recovery email* field is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//label[@for='notificationEmail']//following::div[@class='signupIframe-iframe']/iframe[@title='Registration form']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='notificationEmail']"))).send_keys("manu102")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: recovery]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of related discussions in:

- [Unable to type within username field within ProtonMail signup page using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365613/unable-to-type-within-username-field-within-protonmail-signup-page-using-seleniu/62366143#62366143)
- [How to send text to the Password field within https://mail.protonmail.com registration page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142447/how-to-send-text-to-the-password-field-within-https-mail-protonmail-com-regist/57143455#57143455)

---

### Outro

A couple of useful discussions:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: thanks for your help but the other comments did the job aswell.